# Auto factory reset - is this a general function of Android?

Tags: security, factory-reset, password-protection

I want to install a software provided by my company but the IT admins only accept devices that support the "Auto factory reset" functionality (automatically perform a factory after if the wrong lock screen password/PIN has been entered 15 times consecutively). They claim nearly every Android phone would have this function.

I know that certain Samsung phones have this functionality but Samsung is known to heavily modify Android. So my main question is:

**Is or was the "Auto factory reset" functionality ever included in general Android?**

I have checked multiple devices with different Android versions running. And except from Samsung no device had this functionality, so I am a bit confused...

Comment: "Auto-factory reset" after a set number of failed PIN/password attempts is a part of the [Android Device Admin API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin) which is now available only as a proprietary service from Google, called *"Android Enterprise"*. See point 3 of [section 2.3.3](https://developers.google.com/android/work/requirements#2.3.-advanced-passcode-management_1).

Comment: Or you can build an admin app of your own which sets policy by calling [`setMaximumFailedPasswordsForWipe`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#setMaximumFailedPasswordsForWipe(android.content.ComponentName,%20int)).